# What files pc send to usb device

Tags: usb, monitor, traffic, sniffing

I would like to know if there is a program for analyzing traffic through USB. For example, I would like to know what files are transmitted from the computer to the device at the moment, what he does with the device. I need it to debug device, not driver! Is there such a program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this site as a starting point and inspect the different methods in detail on your own.

[wireshark wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB)